# Why printf is not working with multple threads in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, printf, pthread-join

In the code below I create 8 threads and each of those prints a string and its id. However, I don't see any `printf` output in `stdout` from `PrintHello` function. One strange thing that is happening is that if run the `main` using debugger (CLion) `printf` indeed outputs the intended output. I actually suspect that no code inside  `PrintHello` function is run, not just `printf`. What could be causing this?

Also according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586682/how-to-use-printf-in-multiple-threads) `printf` is thread-safe so it shouldn't be an issue of different threads competing for `stdout`.

This is the code (it as adapted from these [slides](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/fa2010/ppt/10-pthread-examples.pdf)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ntsid.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BAD_EXIT 1
#define NUM_TASKS 8

char * messages[NUM_TASKS];

void * PrintHello(void * taskIdPtr) {
    int taskId;
    sleep(1);
    taskId = *((int *) taskIdPtr);
    printf("Task id = %d, message = %s\n", taskId, messages[taskId]);
    free(taskIdPtr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_TASKS];
    int * taskIdPtr;
    int rc, t;
    messages[0] = "English: Hello World!";
    messages[1] = "French: Bonjour, le monde!";
    messages[2] = "Spanish: Hola al mundo";
    messages[3] = "Klingon: Nuq neH!";
    messages[4] = "German: Guten Tag, Welt!";
    messages[5] = "Russian: Zdravstvytye, mir!";
    messages[6] = "Japan: Sekai e konnichiwa!";
    messages[7] = "Latin: Orbis, te saluto!";

    for(t = 0; t < NUM_TASKS; t++) {
        taskIdPtr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *taskIdPtr = t;
        printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *) taskIdPtr);
        if(rc) {
            perror("Error :");
            exit(BAD_EXIT);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should wait for the threads created using `pthread_join`

Comment: Your program exits as soon as the **main thread** exits. Well, in your code, that happens right after you created all the other threads, while they are still blocked at `sleep(1)`.

Comment: side notes: there are simpler  ways to initialize an array of strings, the `malloc()` can be avoided (e.g. using an array of `int`, or maybe with `intptr_t` cast to `void *`), and there's a standard define for an error exit: `EXIT_FAILURE` -- so don't define your own.

Comment: @FelixPalmen thank you for the side notes, and by the way, isn't the only reason we use `malloc` is that if `PrintHello` somehow modified `taskIdPtr` then other iterations of the loop wouldn't be affected? But if `PrintHello` doesn't modify `taskIdPtr` coulnd't I pass `t` as the last argument to `pthread_create`?

Comment: The reason to pass a pointer is that `pthreads` define the interface that way. `void *` has the advantage that you can actually pass (a pointer to) anything. If you'd just pass a pointer to your `t`, however, by the time your thread function accesses it, it will be changed by the `for` loop. So when passing a pointer to an `int`, you have to make sure each thread gets its own instance. But `malloc()` isn't the only way to do that, you could just prepare an `int` array (like you do with your strings) and pass each thread a pointer to one of its elements.

Comment: @Yos just passing `t` (**not** a pointer) wouldn't be correct, there's no guarantee any value of an `int` "survives" a roundtrip when converted into a pointer and back. But there's the type `intptr_t` that gives that guarantee, so you could simply make your `t` of that type and pass it directly, cast to `void *`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I tried passing `&t` to `pthread_create` and using join and I get an output of 8 strings which **all**  say "Task id = 0, message = English: Hello World!". According to your explanation I'd think that for example currently `t=0` then I pass it to `pthread_create` and by that time `t=1` already. Then `PrintHello` would print out the 2nd string and id=1. But this is not what's happening. Did I understand your explanation correctly?

Comment: @Yos I just told you passing `&t` is the **one** thing you **can't** do. What I explained was an example of what could happen -- it's not possible to predict as you can't know how your OS will schedule the threads. The thing is, your `main()` continues to modify `t`, so passing a pointer to it to a thread will of course not work correctly.

Comment: @FelixPalmen  `intptr_t` is able to hold any pointer value. Nowhere it is said that a pointer is able to hold any `intptr_t` value. Round-trip of pointer to intptr_t to pointer is guaranteed to work. Round trip of intptr_t to pointer to intptr_t is not. In practice it will work for small enough integers of any type, but no guarantee is given,

Comment: @n.m. yes, I thought it was guaranteed in POSIX though .... but can't find a reference right now, maybe I'm remembering wrong here

Comment: By the way, another possible solution of the problem is to call `pthread_exit(NULL)` as the last thing from `main` without calling `pthread_join`. Then `main` will block and wait for other threads to terminate. Found this here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main process is exiting before the newly created threads gets executed. So you should wait for the threads created using `pthread_join`.

As per the man page of `pthread_join`

`int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);`

The  pthread_join()  function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by thread must be joinable.

Comment: That's cool as a comment, but for a (good) answer, I'd expect **some** explanation.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Edited the answer

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your *main thread* completes its execution and exits before any other child thread even prints a single message(Since in your child thread you are waiting for 1 second before doing anything).

As soon as the *main thread* exits, all other child threads also exits and you don't see any message on your screen.

Following is an extract of linux manual page of [`pthread_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> **The new thread terminates in one of the following ways**:
>
> - It calls pthread_exit(3), specifying an exit status value that is available to another thread in the same process that calls pthread_join(3).
> - It returns from start_routine().  This is equivalent to calling pthread_exit(3) with the value supplied in the return statement.
> - It is canceled (see pthread_cancel(3)).
> - Any of the threads in the process calls exit(3), or **the main thread performs a return from main()**.  This causes the termination of all threads in the process.

To solve this problem you should use [`int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).

Following is corrected code. See it [working here](https://ideone.com/5tAUMd):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BAD_EXIT 1
#define NUM_TASKS 8

char * messages[NUM_TASKS];

void * PrintHello(void * taskIdPtr) {
    int taskId;
    sleep(1);
    taskId = *((int *) taskIdPtr);
    printf("Task id = %d, message = %s\n", taskId, messages[taskId]);
    free(taskIdPtr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_TASKS];
    int * taskIdPtr;
    int rc, t;
    messages[0] = "English: Hello World!";
    messages[1] = "French: Bonjour, le monde!";
    messages[2] = "Spanish: Hola al mundo";
    messages[3] = "Klingon: Nuq neH!";
    messages[4] = "German: Guten Tag, Welt!";
    messages[5] = "Russian: Zdravstvytye, mir!";
    messages[6] = "Japan: Sekai e konnichiwa!";
    messages[7] = "Latin: Orbis, te saluto!";

    for(t = 0; t < NUM_TASKS; t++) {
        taskIdPtr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *taskIdPtr = t;
        printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *) taskIdPtr);
        if(rc) {
            perror("Error :");
            exit(BAD_EXIT);
        }
    }

    for(t = 0; t < NUM_TASKS; t++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```