# How to modify the code so that both threads keep printing the same line, so that the terminal shows ’A’ and ’B’ interleaved

Tags: c++, pthreads

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int value = 0;
void *runner(void *param);
int main(){
    int pid;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
      pthread_attr_init(&attr);
      pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,NULL);
      pthread_join(tid,NULL);
      printf("A: value = %d\n", value);
    }

    else if (pid > 0) {
     wait(NULL);
     printf("B: value = %d\n", value);
    }
}

void *runner(void *param){
    value = 5;
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I have identified the child and parent processes but I am not sure how to make A and B print interleaved.

Comment: If you want "ABABABAB.." you need synchronization between the threads so they wait on eachother after printing a single character. Otherwise each thread will print as much as it can while it has the CPU and any mix of output is possible.

Comment: Notice that we have now (since C++11) [`<thread>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread) instead of `pthread_*`.

Comment: Why are you using raw pthreads in C++? What's wrong with [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and friends?

Comment: @JesperJuhl @Jarod42 It is how my professor wants us to type our code. I've read that we can now use `<thread>` but he does not want that.

Comment: @Shayra In my opinion, your professor is behind the times...

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586682/how-to-use-printf-in-multiple-threads ? I'm assuming you are having the two threads printing over each other and producing garbled output. If you just want them intersperced ABAB then use a loop. Threads are contrary to that -- you're not supposed to control when each one does stuff.

Comment: @Shayra what is the desired output in your case ?

Comment: If you want the threads to wait for each other, that is certainly achievable, but you have not even attempted it in your code. You'll have to make an attempt before you post that question.

Comment: Why `fork` *and* start a single thread? That thread doesn't do anything, the main thread starts it and immediately waits for it to finish. If this is a thread synchronization question, the `fork` doesn't belong. If this is a process synchronization question, the extra thread doesn't belong.